# Problem building Docker image for python app using a forked Flask github repository

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, flask

I've been trying to get this Ubuntu docker image for a Flask app to build correctly for a bit now, but it never successfully builds. I'm trying to create a Python Flask app which runs off of a forked version of the Flask github repository. The only changes made to this github repository were in setup.py, where the dependencies are replaced with other forked dependencies. When I run "docker build -t test ." I get the following error:

```
Obtaining flask from git+git://github.com/ectoglasses/flask.git#egg=flask (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
  Cloning git://github.com/ectoglasses/flask.git to ./src/flask
  Running command git clone -q git://github.com/ectoglasses/flask.git /app/src/flask
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/app/src/flask/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/app/src/flask/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info
         cwd: /app/src/flask/
    Complete output (33 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/app/src/flask/setup.py", line 4, in <module>
        setup(
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 121, in setup
        dist.parse_config_files()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 701, in parse_config_files
        parse_configuration(self, self.command_options,
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 121, in parse_configuration
        meta.parse()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 426, in parse
        section_parser_method(section_options)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 399, in parse_section
        self[name] = value
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 184, in __setitem__
        value = parser(value)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 515, in _parse_version
        version = self._parse_attr(value, self.package_dir)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 349, in _parse_attr
        module = import_module(module_name)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/app/src/flask/src/flask/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from markupsafe import escape
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'markupsafe'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y python3-pip && apt-get install -y git && pip3 install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I've previously used Alpine for this project, and did not encounter this same error. I've also tried using the version of Flask hosted on Pypi to see if the problem was with the package itself, but did not get any errors. This tells me that this has something to do with how pip works on Ubuntu, given the code that is producing these results, which I've posted below.

Dockerfile:

```
# Use Google Cloud SDK's container as the base image
FROM ubuntu:20.04

...

# Copy the contents of the current directory into the container directory /app
COPY . /app

# Set the working directory of the container to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Install the Python packages specified by requirements.txt into the container
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip && apt-get install -y git && pip3 install -r requirements.txt

CMD python3 app.py
```

requirements.txt:

```
# Python framework
-e git://github.com/ectoglasses/flask.git#egg=flask
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what could cause this error?

Answer (score 0):

from the error it looks like the module `markupsafe` is missing. The Dockerfile can use some caching improvements as well.

e.g.

```
# Use Google Cloud SDK's container as the base image
FROM ubuntu:20.04

...

COPY requirements.txt /app/

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y \ 
            python3-pip \
            python-markupsafe \
            git

# Install the Python packages specified by requirements.txt into the container
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the contents of the current directory into the container directory /app
COPY . /app

CMD python3 app.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I located the issue. The issue is at `setup.cfg` file line 3 `version = attr: flask.__version__`. During the docker build stage of `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`, it will load `setup.cfg` file before install any dependency. When it loads `setup.cfg` file, it will load `flask` module (the `__init__.py` file) to find `__version__` attribute. It throws error because none of the dependencies listed in `__init__.py` is installed yet.

It seems a bug in Ubuntu environment. I have no issue to run in macOS. You can have a quick fix by changing `version = 1.0` in `setup.cfg` file.